# IE 11 only: ReactDOM.createPortal() error: Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer

When I import ReactDom in my modal component to use the createPortal method the Modal works in all browsers except IE 11. But if I fail to import ReactDOM then the Modal works in all browsers, including IE 11.

```
// Component file
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'; // removing this line allows modal to work in all browsers including IE 11

export default class Modal extends React.Component {

    ...

    getModalWrapper() {
        return (
            <div className="Modal-overlay">
                <div className="Modal-content">{this.props.children}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            ReactDOM.createPortal(this.getModalWrapper(), this.el)
        );
    }
}
```

When I don't include the import of ReactDOM in this file the modal works in all browsers. But, in my tests naturally it errors saying `ReactDOM` is not defined.

The error I get in IE 11 (and only in IE 11, the other browsers all work fine, including Edge) is:

`Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, key, children, containerInfo, implementation}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Other info:

React Version: 16.4.0

React Dom Version: 16.4.0

Comment: Do you have the same error if you build the project? I assume you used [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) so you can build with `npm run build`

Comment: @HMR this was not built with create-react-app, but was manually configured on top of an older Ruby app.